# Using LWP to get webpage contents

Tags: perl, lwp

I'm trying to use LWP::UserAgent to gather contents of a webpage, but for some reason when I run the script I get a Windows pop-up saying:

> Perl Command Line Interpreter has stopped working

I can't figure out why as I have simplified to the code to its bare essentials in the following:

```
#!C:/Perl/bin/Perl.exe
use LWP::UserAgent;

$URL = 'http://www.google.com';

my $oHTTPAgent = new LWP::UserAgent;
$oRequest = HTTP::Request->new('GET');
$oRequest->url($URL);
$sResponse = $oHTTPAgent->request($oRequest);
if ($sResponse->is_success) {
    $sPage = $sResponse->content;
}

print $sPage;
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: that looks like it should work, it's not a code problem, have you tried running perl directly on the script ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean running perl directly on the script? I run this script from the command line. Originally this code chunk is from a larger piece of code that makes up a web form.

Comment: i mean try to run C:\Perl\bin\Perl.exe C:\path\to\script.pl

Comment: Does this perl binary run other scripts ?

Answer (score 3):

You're hitting google.com, which doesn't allow robots. I don't know if that's your problem, but you don't have another branch if you get an unsuccessful response. At the end of your Perl program, your program shuts down without printing anything.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

$url = 'http://www.perl.com';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get( $url );
print $response->content if $response->is_success;

print "I'm done!\n";
```

You might also be interested in [Mojo::UserAgent](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent):

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;

$url = 'http://www.perl.com';

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
print $ua->get( $url )->res->body;

print "I'm done!\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

A few common things to be considered while scripting:

- Add `use strict;`
- Add `use warnings;`

Does the path `C:/Perl/bin/Perl.exe` exists? The shebang{#} should be pointed to the path where Perl has been installed.

A few variables used in the code are not declared, and after modification the code looks like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $URL = 'http://www.google.com';
my $oHTTPAgent = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $oRequest = HTTP::Request->new('GET');
$oRequest->url($URL);
my $sResponse = $oHTTPAgent->request($oRequest);
if ($sResponse->is_success) {
    my $sPage = $sResponse->content;
    print $sPage;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this code word for word, still gives the same error. I believe it is not a syntax or logic error, but something to do with windows. I've tried the above code with different webpages to no avail. Perhaps its something to do with my install. Mind you, I have run plenty of other Perl scripts on this computer (that don't use LWP) and have had no problems. Weird.